# How to remove license dialog from the Wix installer built in UI WixUI_Minimal

Tags: wix, installation

For customizing the dialog order I tried to follow the instructions provided in the WixToolSet site (Link[wix recommended steps](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_customizations.html)) but failed to achieve result.

Steps done:

- Copied the UI from the source code to a new wxs file.
- Changed the id of th UI element
- Build the project without any further modification.

The above steps results in following error.

Error   4   Duplicate symbol 'ControlEvent:WelcomeDlg/Next/NewDialog/VerifyReadyDlg/Installed AND PATCH' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated.
 Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.

My intent is to make changed in installui sequence and build the solution but I couldn't proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir">
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
    <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />

    <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="DiskCostDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
    <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
    <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
    <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />

    <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">Installed
AND PATCH</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SetTargetPath"
Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath"
Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg"
Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg"
Order="4">WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH OR WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID="1"</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty"
Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg"
Order="1">NOT Installed</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg"
Order="2">Installed AND NOT PATCH</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg"
Order="2">Installed AND PATCH</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
    <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

    <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
</UI>
<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
```

Reference : http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.windows.devel.wix.user/65550

Answer (score 1):

Thanks LeoN.

I have done more experimentation and found a solution.
Steps :

- Copied the UI from the source code (WixUI_Minimal.wxs) to product
  cont.
- Changed the id of the UI element Removed the uisequence element
- Modified the UI conditions. Build the project it was working fine.

Modified Code pasted below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<UI Id="WixUI_MinimalX">
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
  <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

  <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
  <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="Minimal" />

  <DialogRef Id="ErrorDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="FatalError" />
  <DialogRef Id="FilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
  <DialogRef Id="PrepareDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ProgressDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="ResumeDlg" />
  <DialogRef Id="UserExit" />
  <DialogRef Id="WelcomeDlg" />

  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" Order="999">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceTypeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>

  <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
  <Publish Dialog="VerifyReadyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="WelcomeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>


  <Property Id="ARPNOMODIFY" Value="1" />
</UI>

<UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />

<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"/>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixInstallerStudy" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixInstallerStudy" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
         <Component Id="ProductComponent">         
     <File Id='Test.Txt' Name='Test.Txt' DiskId='1' Source='.\2.0\Test.txt' KeyPath='yes' DefaultVersion='1.0' Checksum='yes'>
     </File>
   </Component>
   <Component Id="ProductComponent2">
    <File Id='TestCopy.txt' Name='Test - Copy.txt' DiskId='1' Source='.\2.0\Test - Copy.txt' KeyPath='yes' >
    </File>
  </Component>

    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Found that if the ui sequence is there it will give you many unexpected errors.